# Break a single entry into an arbitrary number of pages?

Tags: pagination

The [documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/entry-spanning.html) describes using separate fields to create pages for an entry. But how can I create pages arbitrarily? There are multiple reasons I don't want to create a separate field for each page. The [Simple Pagination plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-pagination) looks like what I want, but it isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of either a built feature or an add-on that will let you break a long entry in to smaller chunks in a way that will let you spread these across several pages, but others might.

There are possibly ways that you could achieve this result within EE without an add-on, but they would be non-trivial solutions to implement.

I suspect it would be easier to do this within the page using javascript / css (i.e. send the whole entry to the page, and do the chunking of the entry into blocks in javascript, or simply use CSS to allow the text part to scroll on that window within its block etc.

HTH